# Can't automate user creation with xubuntu.pressed

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, ubiquity

I'm installing xubuntu 22.04 and can't set the password automatically, my xubuntu.pressed file:
Please help.
Ty.

```
#### LOCALES ####

d-i debian-installer/locale string ru_RU.UTF-8





#### KEYBOARD ####

d-i debian-installer/keymap string ru

d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false

d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select ru

d-i keyboard-configuration/toggle select No toggling



#### NETWORK ####

d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto

d-i netcfg/get_hostname string machine

#d-i netcfg/get_domain string machine



#### CLOCK ####

d-i clock-setup/utc boolean true

d-i time/zone string UTC



#### USERS ####

d-i passwd/user-fullname string smartix

ubiquity ubiquity/passwd/username string smartix

ubiquity ubiquity/passwd/password string smartix

ubiquity ubiquity/passwd/user-uid string 1010



d-i passwd/user-password-crypted password $6$coYysd63KbDoJSnI$E0SPRvH7v7cox4IcPS1nZXH/5a.bUCt9PdQ.kn.OByHkAqp6SRfqmsDmZnCCHgc4xDZ7CQ0VtmF9helgQ/t4z0

d-i passwd/user-password-again $6$coYysd63KbDoJSnI$E0SPRvH7v7cox4IcPS1nZXH/5a.bUCt9PdQ.kn.OByHkAqp6SRfqmsDmZnCCHgc4xDZ7CQ0VtmF9helgQ/t4z0

d-i user-setup/allow-password-weak boolean true

d-i passwd/user-uid string 1010



#### PARTITIONING ####

##d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda

d-i partman-auto/method string raid

d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true

d-i partman-md/confirm boolean true

d-i partman-partitioning/confirm_write_new_label boolean true

##d-i partman/choose_partition select finish

##d-i partman/confirm boolean true

##d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true







#### APT ####

d-i apt-setup/non-free boolean false

d-i apt-setup/extras boolean true



#### At last ###

tasksel tasksel/first   multiselect xubuntu-desktop

ubiquity ubiquity/reboot



ubiquity ubiquity/download_updates boolean false

ubiquity ubiquity/use_nonfree boolean false
```